# Python variable can not be same name as function it is calling like it is possible in PHP?

Tags: python

in php this is possible:

```
function a():
   return "b"

 a = a()
```

but in python.. i have no choice but to change the name of my variable to something else..

```
 a1 = a()
```

"a" simply needs to eat "a" and thus become what "a" is. and the new "a" is what it ate which is "a()" function's output.

why is this logic being ignored in python and not in php ?

Comment: I'm not sure I get what you're trying to do.  `a = a()` does work in Python, it just replaces `a` with the return value of the function.  I can't tell from your description about "eating" if that's what you want or not.  Either way, if you're asking "why do PHP and Python work differently", the answer is "because they're different languages".

Comment: You might want to take your time to learn the basics of Python. There is no keyword named `function` (it's called `def`) and a `return` outside of a function is invalid syntax.

Comment: seems to work ok .. perhaps it is my wsgi script.. causing problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP variables and functions use different syntax. The variable is `$a`, the function is just `a`, so there's no confusion.

In Python, functions and variables use the same syntax and share the same namespace. If you were to do:

```
a = a()
```

then `a` would no longer contain a function, it would contain the result of calling the function.

Basically, a named function is just a variable whose value is a function.

Comment: PHP has *different namespaces* for functions and variables, the $ just hides the fact (and does eliminate confusion) by making it appear to be different by some sigil in a single namespace. See http://ideone.com/9m9mom - note the name of the variable *is* "say_hi", which is also the exact name of the function.

Comment: @user4011218 Try assigning a function to a variable in PHP, as in `def a(): return 1; f = a; f()`;

Answer (score 1):

Python (unlike PHP) does *not* have a separate namespace for variables and functions.

When you call a function in Python, you actually just *evaluate an expression* (eg. `a`) which evaluates to a function object and then *invoke* the function (eg. with `()`) - this is because Python has [first-class functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function).

So if the variable (which can be referring to a function which is just a value) is assigned a different value, then it will evaluate to that new value.

In PHP, however, when a function call is made it looks up the function in the function namespace (which is *different* from the namespace for variables) and then invokes it. Variables start with `$` in PHP code which helps makes them appear different from function names, but there are still [different namespaces](http://ideone.com/9m9mom) used internally that do not overlap. There are additional big differences in the namespaces, eg. functions are always "global".